# Scan and read files from dependency jar

Tags: java, maven, spring-boot, jar

I'm developing a spring boot command-line app that consumes a large data set. The data set is cumbersome so I'd like to separate it from my code, but I don't want to burden the user with having to manage the data either.

I think the ideal solution would be to create a data jar and have the main application read from it. Unfortunately I've not been able to successfully read the data when its in a dependency jar.

I've made an example app to demonstrate what I've attempted so far

https://github.com/LewisWatson/java-data-jar

`.
├── data-jar
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           └── resources
│               └── data
│                   ├── hellos
│                   │   └── hello.txt
│                   └── loremIpsums
│                       └── loremIpsum.txt
├── data-jar-reader
│   ├── pom.xml
│   └── src
│       └── main
│           ├── java
│           │   └── com
│           │       └── example
│           │           └── datajarreader
│           │               └── DataJarReaderApplication.java
│           └── resources
│               └── application.properties
├── LICENSE
├── pom.xml
└── README.md`

It has two modules:

- `data-jar` contains two text files inside two directories in side a `data` directory in the standard resources directory for maven.
- `data-jar-reader` is spring boot command line application that has a dependency on `data-jar` and attempts to access its data files.

The class that does the reading is [DataJarReaderApplication](https://github.com/LewisWatson/java-data-jar/blob/master/data-jar-reader/src/main/java/com/example/datajarreader/DataJarReaderApplication.java)

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class DataJarReaderApplication implements CommandLineRunner {

  private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(DataJarReaderApplication.class);

  FileSystem fileSystem;

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(DataJarReaderApplication.class, args);
  }

  @Override
  public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    Path path = getTestDataPath();
    List<String> data = loadTestData(path);
    log.info("data {}", data);
  }

  private Path getTestDataPath() throws URISyntaxException, IOException {

    Path path;

    URI uri = this.getClass().getResource("/data").toURI();
    log.info("uri: {}", uri);

    if (uri.getScheme().equals("jar")) {
      fileSystem = FileSystems.newFileSystem(uri, Collections.<String, Object>emptyMap());
      log.info("fileSystem: {}", fileSystem);
      path = fileSystem.getPath("/data");
    } else { // not in a jar, probably running in iDE
      path = Paths.get(uri);
    }

    return path;
  }

  private List<String> loadTestData(Path testDataDirectory) throws IOException {
    try (Stream<Path> path = Files.walk(testDataDirectory).sorted()) {
      return loadTrackData(path);
    }
  }

  private List<String> loadTrackData(Stream<Path> walk) throws IOException {

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    for (Iterator<Path> it = walk.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {

      Path path = it.next();

      if (path.getFileName().toString().endsWith(".txt")) {

        log.info("text file path: {}", path);

        List<String> dataFromFile = getData(path);
        data.addAll(dataFromFile);

      } else {

        log.info("non text file path: {}", path);

      }

    }

    return data;
  }

  private List<String> getData(Path path) throws IOException {

    List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();

    try (BufferedReader reader = Files.newBufferedReader(path, StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {

      String line;

      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        data.add(line);
      }

    }
    return data;
  }
}
```

The output I get when I run the application shows that its finding the data in the data jar

```
jar:file:/home/lewis/workspace/java-data-jar/data-jar-reader/target/data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/data-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/data
```

but when it tries to access the data I get a no such file exception...

```
$ java -jar data-jar-reader/target/data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar 

  .   ____          _            __ _ _
 /\\ / ___'_ __ _ _(_)_ __  __ _ \ \ \ \
( ( )\___ | '_ | '_| | '_ \/ _` | \ \ \ \
 \\/  ___)| |_)| | | | | || (_| |  ) ) ) )
  '  |____| .__|_| |_|_| |_\__, | / / / /
 =========|_|==============|___/=/_/_/_/
 :: Spring Boot ::        (v1.5.7.RELEASE)

2017-10-16 09:35:46.238  INFO 18756 --- [           main] c.e.d.DataJarReaderApplication           : Starting DataJarReaderApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT on mir with PID 18756 (/home/lewis/workspace/java-data-jar/data-jar-reader/target/data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar started by lewis in /home/lewis/workspace/java-data-jar)
2017-10-16 09:35:46.249  INFO 18756 --- [           main] c.e.d.DataJarReaderApplication           : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2017-10-16 09:35:46.376  INFO 18756 --- [           main] s.c.a.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext : Refreshing org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@443b7951: startup date [Mon Oct 16 09:35:46 BST 2017]; root of context hierarchy
2017-10-16 09:35:47.049  INFO 18756 --- [           main] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Registering beans for JMX exposure on startup
2017-10-16 09:35:47.056  INFO 18756 --- [           main] c.e.d.DataJarReaderApplication           : uri: jar:file:/home/lewis/workspace/java-data-jar/data-jar-reader/target/data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar!/BOOT-INF/lib/data-jar-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar!/data
2017-10-16 09:35:47.094  INFO 18756 --- [           main] c.e.d.DataJarReaderApplication           : fileSystem: /home/lewis/workspace/java-data-jar/data-jar-reader/target/data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
2017-10-16 09:35:47.098  INFO 18756 --- [           main] utoConfigurationReportLoggingInitializer : 

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the auto-configuration report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2017-10-16 09:35:47.111 ERROR 18756 --- [           main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application startup failed

java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to execute CommandLineRunner
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:735) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:716) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.afterRefresh(SpringApplication.java:703) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:304) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1118) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1107) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    at com.example.datajarreader.DataJarReaderApplication.main(DataJarReaderApplication.java:34) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48) [data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87) [data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50) [data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.loader.JarLauncher.main(JarLauncher.java:51) [data-jar-reader-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
Caused by: java.nio.file.NoSuchFileException: /data
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipPath.getAttributes(ZipPath.java:666) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at com.sun.nio.zipfs.ZipFileSystemProvider.readAttributes(ZipFileSystemProvider.java:294) ~[zipfs.jar:1.8.0_131]
    at java.nio.file.Files.readAttributes(Files.java:1737) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.getAttributes(FileTreeWalker.java:219) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.visit(FileTreeWalker.java:276) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeWalker.walk(FileTreeWalker.java:322) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.nio.file.FileTreeIterator.<init>(FileTreeIterator.java:72) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3574) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at java.nio.file.Files.walk(Files.java:3625) ~[na:1.8.0_131]
    at com.example.datajarreader.DataJarReaderApplication.loadTestData(DataJarReaderApplication.java:63) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at com.example.datajarreader.DataJarReaderApplication.run(DataJarReaderApplication.java:40) [classes!/:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:732) [spring-boot-1.5.7.RELEASE.jar!/:1.5.7.RELEASE]
    ... 14 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Are you sure that putting the data in a jar is the best way to go? There are a lot of different options to distribute a large read-only file. If you intend to put that large jar on Maven servers, you are likely to run into trouble.

Comment: you may be right, but for my particular use case I just want to be able to run the app in isolation. This is a test tool so the main requirements are that it needs to be easy to use and repeatable. Other solutions involve separately transferring files (which are roughly 100mb) and introduces opportunities for the files to the altered, thus affecting the results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't have to access your data differently if you are running your application in your IDE or not. These data files are always resources, e.g. files in the classpath and should be loaded as resources.

Spring has a convenient resource loader that helps discover data files in the classpath: [`PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.html).

For example, to get all .txt files in the `data` package:

```
ClassLoader cl = this.getClass().getClassLoader(); 
ResourcePatternResolver resolver = new PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver(cl);
Resource[] resources = resolver.getResources("classpath:/data/**/*.txt") ;
for (Resource resource: resources){
    logger.info(resource.getFilename());
}
```

You can then use [`getInputStream`](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/InputStreamSource.html#getInputStream--) on each resource to read your files.

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. https://github.com/LewisWatson/java-data-jar/blob/96f13938e76ba03104d6e73f177f5a3fd1568ebb/data-jar-reader/src/main/java/com/example/datajarreader/DataJarReaderApplication.java

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you really want to use jar for that, you have several options:

- You can list the data-jar on the classpath and use ClassLoader.getResourceAsStream(relativePathWithinJar).
- You can put the data-jar into some directory and open it as regular ZIP/JAR archive using Java APIs.

In the second case, take a look at JarFile class. To open it, you will have to provide jar-file's path. You can either put it into some hard-coded directory, into current directory or pass some arbitrary path via command line arguments, system properties or something like that. After you open it, you can get individual files as JarEntries by their relative (in-jar) paths.

As with any large files, it's better to avoid using methods that load entire data into memory and stick to methods that provide InputStream for sequential, on-demand reading.